# Force refresh/update on data reading

Tags: android, refresh

I use the following code to get the cpu percetange (something like 62.5465%) but it seems to take a long time to refresh/update unless you manually navigate to another activity and then back. Is there any way to force the information to update every second for example? Any herlp would be appreciated.

```
private String ReadCPUinfo()
 {
  ProcessBuilder cmd;
  String result="";

  try{
   String[] args = {"/system/bin/cat", "/proc/cpuinfo"};
   cmd = new ProcessBuilder(args);

   Process process = cmd.start();
   InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
   byte[] re = new byte[1024];
   while(in.read(re) != -1){
    System.out.println(new String(re));
    result = result + new String(re);
   }
   in.close();
  } catch(IOException ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  return result;
 }
```

Used to display the text in a TextView.

```
device.setText(Html.fromHtml(  
"CPU Speed: "  + readUsage() * 100 
));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Timer` and `TimerTask` can be used.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
MyTimerTask myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();

timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 0, 1000); // 0 Delay, Repeat after 1 second
```

Your `MyTimerTask` should look like this

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                device.setText(Html.fromHtml("CPU Speed: " + readUsage() * 100));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

You can also use this method

```
device.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        device.setText(Html.fromHtml("CPU Speed: " + readUsage() * 100));
    }
}, 1000);
```